# Different padding in Firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, webkit, gecko

I'm facing weirdly inconsistent rendering between Webkit and Gecko.

**Safari**

[image: Safari]

**Firefox**

[image]

The snippet in question is simply a `<li>`-tag with its text content centered over a colored background:

```
<ul class="tags">
    <li>some tag</li>
</ul>
```

And the formatting:

```
ul.tags li {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #806d66;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    padding: 5px 6px 3px;
}
```

In my desperation, I have already changed all relevant units from `em` to `px` and removed line-height related stuff. What am I missing? Thank you for your suggestions!

**Jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/19wsn4y7/13/

Comment: when it comes to font-family, this is somehow expected ... probably sans-serif is not handled the same in both browser

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Thank you. I changed the example from "sans-serif" to "Helvetica, Arial" to rule that one out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be font specific. While my locally installed version of **Arial** is rendered consistently across browser engines, **Helvetica**'s dimensions seem a bit off:

**Safari**

[image: comp safari]

**Firefox**

[image: comp ff]

I still do not understand what is going on, but I'll be able to avoid such issues by using web fonts.
However, I'm still thankful for any further insights!

---

Minimal example at http://jsfiddle.net/19wsn4y7/26/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>HELVETICA</li>
    <li>ARIAL</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    font-family:Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

li:first-child {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

Comment: You got the explanation *web fonts* : unlike default ones they are the same cross browser because their behavior is defined by the font created but the default one are defined by browsers

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look up [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) that normalizes(synchronizes) custom css regardless of browser type.

This will help you achieve cross-browser consistency in rendering your elements.

Comment: I believe the issue is unrelated to CSS normalization: The CSS-originating dimensions are consistent across browsers, but still the font rendering differs.
Consequently, pasting _Normalize.css_ does not solve my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/19wsn4y7/28/